# How to change list of arrays one at the time with a method?

Tags: python

I can't seem to figure out, how to change one array of the list at the time. It seems that I change every array of the list. But I want to change population of motifs one at the time with a mutationF method.

```
import random 
import math

POPULIATION_SIZE = 5
chromosome = ["CGGGGCTGGGTCGTCACATTCCCCTTTCGATA", "TTTGAGGGTGCCCAATAACCAAAGCGGACAAA", "GGGATGCCGTTTGACGACCTAAATCAACGGCC", "AAGGCCAGGAGCGCCTTTGCTGGTTCTACCTG", "AATTTTCTAAAAAGATTATAATGTCGGTCCTC", "CTGCTGTACAACTGAGATCATGCTGCTTCAAC", "TACATGATCTTTTGTGGATGAGGGAATGATGC"]
motif_length = 8
motif_positions = [0 for i in range(len(chromosome))]

def mutationF(motif_pos):
  for i in range(0, len(motif_pos)):
    mutation = random.random()
    if mutation <= 0.33 and motif_pos[i] - 1 >= 0:
      motif_pos[i] = motif_pos[i] - 1
    if mutation > 0.33 and mutation <= 0.66 and motif_pos[i] + 1 <= len(chromosome[0]) - motif_length:
      motif_pos[i] = motif_pos[i] + 1
  return motif_pos

repeat = False

population = []
for i in range(0, POPULIATION_SIZE):
  population.append(motif_positions)
print(population)

while not repeat:
  for i in range(0, POPULIATION_SIZE):
    motif_positions2 = population[0]
    motif_positions2 = mutationF(motif_positions2)
    population.append(motif_positions2)
    population.pop(0)
    print(motif_positions2)
    print(population)
  repeat = True
```

[Here are print results:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UM6rU.png)

Tried some things which didn't seem to work.

Comment: Yes.  There is only one `motif_positions` list, and your `population` list contains 5 references to that one list.  Change one, you change them all.  Try `population = [[0]*len(chromosome) for _ in range(POPULATION_SIZE)]`.  Skip the `motif_positions` list.

Comment: You don't change every array of the list, you change the same array multiple times, because in the list are not seperate arrays but references to the same array.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> for i in range(0, POPULIATION_SIZE):
>   population.append(motif_positions)
> ```

You are appending `POPULIATION_SIZE` references to the same list into `population`.

We can see this idea at work below:

```
>>> a = [4,5,6]
>>> b = []
>>> for _ in range(5): b.append(a)
... 
>>> b
[[4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> b[1][0] = 1
>>> b
[[1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6]]
```

If you want to append multiplies *copies* of a list, the easiest way is to use `[:]` to make a copy of a list, as shown below.

```
>>> b = []
>>> for _ in range(5): b.append(a[:])
... 
>>> b
[[1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6]]
>>> b[1][0] = 3
>>> b
[[1, 5, 6], [3, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6], [1, 5, 6]]
```